# load cookies from requests to Selenium browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

how load session and cookies from `requests` to `Selenium` browser? and how inverse?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
session = requests.session()
session.get('https://www.google.com/')
?????
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 1):

for load cookie from requests to selenium

```
ses = requests.session()
ses.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
for item in ses.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(
        {'httpOnly': False, 'name': item.name, 'value': item.value, 'domain': item.domain, 'path': item.path,
         'secure': item.secure})
```

for load cookie from selenium to requests:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], path=cookie['path'])
```